# What would be a oauth2 standard to provide access token to a third party. ? (not involving secret)

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, standards

I am having a hard time finding an oauth2 standard to provide access tokens to third party data consumers. The problem is that most of oauth2 standards involve a secret known by both the auth-server and the third party.
However, my requirement is for a system established on-premise and I am  not able to provide secrets to connecting data consumers in advance.
Do you have any recommendation regarding which standard of oauth2 could be used in this situation ?
Thank you !

Comment: Client ID is not a secret. However, you have not provided enough details to answer your question. Define what you mean by "flow". In summary, you will need to specify the OAuth vendor, use their "flow" on your servers and send the response to the client containing the token (Access Token or Identity Token). Edit your question with more specifics.

Comment: I think you should use implicit flow as it does not require the use of a client secret https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2